# How do i phonegap notification push when new records on webservice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I developed a phonegap project.I am getting data(json) on web service.So when new records on webservice,Phonegap should be announced.I want to do it in 5 minutes, checking and if there is a new record,announced.So it should already work in the background.How can i do that?I am new at the phonegap so i need a lot of help.Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I know I need to use ajax.but how can i already work in the background such as service,and I do not want to use native code.maybe i can set setinterval(func,timer). but How do I make the background?

Comment: You can do this using ajax call with time Intervel using this plugin .https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-fetch

Comment: this plugin looks good,hopefully I can seamlessly use.thanks a lot